# Airflow task in status 'scheduled' and stucks

Tags: airflow

I run `backfill` command and all preceeding tasks are done except for the last 4 tasks.Their status are `scheduled` and nothing happens at all. I have run `airflow test` before and succeeded,but now I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

> I specified a none-existing pool.But I think this won't matter because
>   preceeding tasks run smoothly.

Uhm no;

- AFAIK, non-existent pool results in tasks getting stuck into a **limbo state**
- But I've found that even while DAG is running, adding / removing pools or modifying the count of slots in pool works; so try creating the pool with adequate number of slots

Comment: I specified a pool and run it again and unfortunately it still got stuck in the same place

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to join the conversation. Currently, I already created the pool with adequate number of slots, but the problem is still here. As this picture shows us: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRwVG.png)

And besides, I set the priority_weight of the dag. It works! These tasks begin to running. The change like this:

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'Airflow',
'retries': 2,
'queue': 'queue_name',
'pool': 'pool_name',
'priority_weight': 10, # the larger the number, the higher the weight
'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=10)}
```

Comment: It's also possible that the number of parallelizers is not enough, which requires adjusting it base on server performance. By adjusting "parallelism", like this: parallelism =100